# How to undo git checkout file for uncommitted changes?

Tags: git

I did a `git status` and noticed a bunch of files that were staged that should have been ignored by `git ignore`, such as `.gitignore`, `.htaccess`, and settings files for my Drupal site.

I mistakenly used `git checkout <file>` instead of `git rm <file>` to remove them from the staging area. While it looked like it worked, I broke the website. I think I now understand that `git checkout` reverts any changes I've made to those files, correct? The changes weren't committed because they weren't supposed to be tracked in the first place.

How is `git checkout <file>` supposed to be used and what is the opposite of it? Most importantly, how can I undo the undo or where do I go from here?

Comment: I use git checkout <file> when I want to get back the revision from HEAD onto the working tree (even works with other revisions, ```git checkout <revision> -- <file>```. Now, I don't quite understand what happened afterwards. Say file .htaccess was one of those files.... If you did ```git checkout .htaccess``` and the file was not on HEAD then I don't know exactly how git would react. Let me try over here. Yep, git complains about the file not being there. If that's the case, I can't see how git checkout busted those files and how you ended up breaking the website.

Comment: I figured out that it somehow reverted changes I made to those files that were never committed. I recognized the errors, and had to just go back and make all the changes by hand and backup the config files. For now, I'm adding a "local" version of my config files to the repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation of git [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things):

> It’s important to understand that `git checkout -- <file>` is a
>   dangerous command. Any changes you made to that file are gone – Git
>   just copied another file over it. Don’t ever use this command unless
>   you absolutely know that you don’t want the file.

So you can't undo this command.

Comment: 100% true...  With modern IDEs like VS Code, if you still have the file open, your file will look like you have unsaved changes.  So, if you are lucky, you can recover that way.  However, yea, tread lightly with `git checkout` just like `git rebase`.  Sometimes trying to be clever and save 30 seconds, turns into a fun 30 minute exercise in revision control and all of the git commands that we rarely need :-).