# If I run `git checkout -​- .` on branch. Is there any way I can get those files back?

Tags: git, git-checkout

If I have a load of uncommitted file changes and for whatever reason run `git checkout --` on a file and then realise I need it back - is there any means of doing this?

Have tried `git checkout HEAD <filename>` but I imagine HEAD is not where those files exist anymore?

Comment: If you actually wiped out your working directory without committing or stashing, then the changes are usually gone.  An exception to this would be if you had those files open in an IDE such as IntelliJ which maintains local history.  In that case, you could revert to the previous state in local history.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to undo git checkout file for uncommitted changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43127341/how-to-undo-git-checkout-file-for-uncommitted-changes)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+git+checkout

Comment: As a not-immediately-helpful aside, this is a good reason to develop the habit of stashing local changes rather than just overwriting them.

Answer (score 4):

No, git did not write these file states anywhere in the scenario you describe.

However, depending on your context, if you use an advanced enough editor it might have kept your local changes.

Comment: @Tim You know what? I prefer your comment too :-/ I saw it posted at the same second I posted my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try out the below commands maybe one of them will help you out.

If the deletion has not been committed, the command below will restore the deleted file in the working tree.

```
$ git checkout -- <file>
```

You can get a list of all the deleted files in the working tree using the command below.

```
$ git ls-files --deleted
```

If the deletion has been committed, find the commit where it happened, then recover the file from this commit.

```
$ git rev-list -n 1 HEAD -- <file>
$ git checkout <commit>^ -- <file>
```

In case you are looking for the path of the file to recover, the following command will display a summary of all deleted files.

```
$ git log --diff-filter=D --summary
```

Comment: Problem is, if the description is accurate, it's not a deletion that happened. *Changes* were done but not commited and OP did `git checkout -- .` More of the same won't bring back changes. The rest of your answer is general good advice but... I'm afraid it won't help OP for the case at hand.

Comment: Yeah, this is a perfectly reasonable answer, but unfortunately to a different question.